# AngularJS how to abstract a service?

Tags: angularjs

I have a data factory defined in CoffeeScript like:

```
dataModule.factory "Dates", ->
  object:
    value: null
```

and a service defined in CoffeeScript like so:

```
dataModule.service "DatesService",
["$http", "Dates", "Requesting"
($http, Dates, Requesting) ->
  @url = "api/0/dates/"
  @object = Dates.object

  @getFromServer = (object, onSuccess, onError) ->
    Requesting.status = true
    $http.get(@url + getCacheBuster()
    ).success((data, status) ->
      data = null unless _.isObject(data)
      object.value = data
      Requesting.status = false
      if onSuccess
        onSuccess data

    ).error (data, status) ->
      data = null unless _.isObject(data)
      object.value = null
      Requesting.status = false
      if onError
        onError data, status


  @get = (onSuccess, onError) ->
    if null is @object.value
      @getFromServer @object, onSuccess, onError
    else
      if onSuccess
        onSuccess @object.value


  @clear = () ->
    @object.value = null
]
```

I then use the service like this:

```
dataModule.controller "DatesCtrl",
["$scope", "Dates", "DatesService", "Error"
($scope, Dates, DatesService, Error) ->
  $scope.dates = Dates.object
  $scope.error = Error

  $scope.handleError = ->
    $scope.dates.value = null
    $scope.error.value = "Did not get valid information from server."

  $scope.getDates = ->
    DatesService.get (data) ->

      if not data
        $scope.handleError()
        return
    ,
    (data, status) ->
      $scope.handleError()
      return

  $scope.getDates()
]
```

Notice that the service provides a simple caching mechanism.  This is so multiple controllers within the same view can get the data from the service, but the service only asks the server once.

Also notice that the injection of Dates, the @url and @value members are the only things that make this specific DatesService not reusable.  I would like to abstract this service so that I can "derive"/"extend"/"do other thing" a CachedService into specific "concrete" services that have specific dependency injected, a specific @url and a specific @value.

I have three other services that I want to apply the same pattern to, each with their own data factory and url.

This is probably simple but I am struggling with the right vocabulary to properly search for the answer.

Can someone demonstrate the proper language mechanism(s) to do this abstraction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## **BETTER ANSWER**

We figured it out, here's a way you can do it that's both simple and clean.

```
function serviceMaker(service){
  return function($injector, /*default injections like*/ $q, $http){
    //Add shared functionality here
    this.foo = function(){ 
      //to reference dependent variables, I recommend using method access to avoid timing/order issues

      return this.MyURL(); //will be declared in extending service
    };

    //Can use local injections
    this.getPromise = $q.when('Definitely using injection too');

    //Finishes the other injections
    $injector.invoke(service, this);
  };
}

angular.module('test', [])

//Then, setup your service like this
.service('GreatService', serviceMaker(function($rootScope){ /*Can inject like normal!*/
    //remember to declare dependent methods
    this.MyURL= function(){return "http://stackoverflow.com";}

    //Can still add your own things
    this.bar = function(){
      //properties from base service are still accessible
      return this.foo()+"?param=huzzah";
    }
}))

//Another service
.service('NiceService', serviceMaker(function(){
    this.MyURL= function(){return "http://google.com";}
}))
```

This will do what you're looking for, using angular's `$injector` for a clean and straightforward method.

### **OLD, BAD ANSWER JUST FOR CONTEXT**

I solved the same problem using the method described below... I'll claim that it works well, but my team's currently investigating some of the deeper Angular functions to see if it can be cleaned up and feel more natural.

Here's the code for your basic service:

```
var baseService = function(extraInjections, also){
  var serviceFunc = function( /*default injections here, like*/ $http, $q, /*and shame*/ param1, param2, param3, param4)
  {
     //perform other startup stuff set in custom service
     also(this, arguments);

     //apis can be set here, like
     this.getFromURL= function(url){...}

     //do common work here, like caching.
     //You can reference values that may be set in the custom service,
     if(this.url){this.getFromURL(this.url);}

  }


  //then, inject extra dependencies
  var depArray = ['$http', '$q'] //defaults
  depArray = depArray.concat(extraInjections);
  depArray.push(serviceFunc);

  return depArray; //returns service made with dependency array syntax (like ['$q', function($q){}]
}
```

Then, when writing your services,

```
myModule.service("ServiceName", baseService([/*any extra injections, like*/'$rootScope'], function(me, injections){
  //the injections param holds injections, so here,
  var http = injections[0];
  //because $http is the first default injection.
  //Custom ones can be accessed too
  var rootScope = injections[2];

  //now, the 'me' variable is your service.
  //append api as needed
  me.getThatThing = function(){return rootScope.blah};

  //make sure you set any expected values you use in your base service
  me.url = "http://stackoverflow.com";
}
```

Obvious flaw that could be improved upon is that in order to add the extra injections, I have to add that silly `param1, param2, param3` etc. to my `serviceFunc`, so that there's 'room' for the extra custom injections.  However, if you're okay with a little clumsiness, I can verify that this works quite well.

Comment: thanks for the example.  I think I understand.  Can you show where to override the @url and @object?

Comment: Yep, just added an example with url to the answer.

Comment: thanks for your example.  You are right, this is a little clumsy (nothing against you for your inventive solution).  This seems like it should be easier, don't you think?  Basically I want to make a "service class", then instantiate specific concrete instances. (BTW, I do know this is the not the precise correct vocabulary for JavaScript...)

Comment: Yeah, I'm also sure that there IS any easier way to do it that I haven't found yet either... hoping others could expand or improve on my answer.  I have a gut feeling that there's some easy way to do this with angular.extend and the $injector service.  My experience with Angular is that there's always a one-line solution to your question, it's just not always obvious.

Comment: just saw the update to your post (SO didn't alert me to the new awesome info :-) ).  I'll try it and get back to you

Answer (score 3):

I've seen and tried many methods to extend an angular service. The example here - and others which I found work well when extending a service **one** time. When you want to extend an abstract service **multiple** times you could use the following approach:

**Abstract Service Definition**

```
var AbstractCurdlService = function($q, $http) {

    var ENDPOINT = ""; //extend this service

    return {
        setEndpoint : function(value){
            ENDPOINT = value;
        },
        create: function(payload) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({
                method : "POST",
                url : this.ENDPOINT,
                data: payload
            }).then(function(response){
                deferred.resolve(response.data);
            }, function(error){
                deferred.reject(error);
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        },
        /* additional service definitions */
    };
};
```

**AngularJS Service 1**

```
app.factory('customerService', function($q, $http){
    var customerService = new AbstractService($q, $http);
    customerService.setEndpoint("/api/customer");
    return customerService;
});
```

**AngularJS Service 2**

```
app.factory('reportService', function($q, $http){
    var reportService = new AbstractService($q, $http);
    reportService.setEndpoint("/api/report");
    return reportService;
});
```

Comment: This works, and I've done it a lot. However, there are pitfalls. Be aware that if you log what is returned from `customerService` or `reportService` what will show up is `AbstractService`. This can be trouble if you plan on extending the AbstractService. This also affects stack traces, which might make debugging a pain. A better way is to extend the concrete services using prototypal inheritance.